# Sticky toobar title in Parallax effect using CollapsingToolbarLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-toolbar, parallax, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am creating Parallax effect to toolbar using CollapsingToolbarLayout. But I'm having a problem to meet my design. Because before app bar is collapsed, the title is so big and sticks at the bottom. After collapsed, it is stuck to top and become smaller.

This is the screenshot:

[image]

But what I want is I want title always stick at the top like in the second screenshot after or before collapsed.

This is my XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/ai_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/ai_rc_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/ai_fab_review"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/ai_app_bar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is how I set toolbar in activity

```
public class BookActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String BOOK_ID_FIELD;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}
```

How can I fix my code to get what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add `app:titleEnabled="false"`, like below

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:titleEnabled="false"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">
```